# Javascript on Individual Tumblr Post

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I am aware that you can edit the html/AngularJS that renders the all posts blog homepage on a tumblr blog. But, is there any way to add a custom `<script>...</script>` to the individual posts? I want to do some javascript stuff on a post-by-post basis, and cant seem to find where that code can be edited (or, if it even can)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When writing a post, on the menu bar where you can click bold, italic, strikethrough, etc, there is a button that says `<html>`. If you click this, it will bring up the HTML for the post. Then, all you do is have to add a script tag with the javascript code you want. For example:

```
<script>
    alert("Hello World!");
</script>
```

**NOTE:** I believe the javascript will only work when users navigate to your actual page, not when it is in their feed unless the box that is shown to represent extra content is clicked. This is to prevent unnecessary content from showing and keeping load time low in the feed

**EDIT**: If you want the same javascript to apply to all posts you write, I'd put it into the theme's HTML. To do so you'd go to `Customize -> Edit HTML (of the theme) -> put <script> at the bottom of body (generally speaking) or add to an existing <script>`. Each posts has the class `.POST`, so use that selector to obtain each. To find out the classes of individual types you can look at [the Tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts) or use inspect element to find out for yourself

**NOTE: The script added to the theme will not affect posts in user's feed**. It is a change to the theme, thus will not affect individual posts when seen not directly on the site.

Comment: I want this script to be included on every post by default. I don't want to have to manually add it in each time one is written. I am building a blog for a client who has 0 tech knowledge

Comment: @AlexNeigher In that case have you tried adding it to the theme? Go to Customize -> Edit HTML -> enter javascript that you want

Comment: The overall theme code appears to strip all non-native script tags regardless of where they're included (head,body, etc)

Comment: @AlexNeigher It seems to work for me. Try adding a simple alert like I have above to the bottom of the body and see if it works

Comment: it appears to work if I include some js *inside* an already existing script that tumblr has included. Going to work from here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AlexNeigher Updated my answer to suit

Comment: it also appears as though there is *significant* caching going on where a completely new incognito window is necessary to rapidly see changes made. Seems to be working just find now, thanks!