# playing music from tumblr posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I would like to ask, if it is possible to construct an embedded player, which plays music from tumblr posts. My main goal is to set up a radio-like page, which is not based on shoutcast, rather on blog posts. So for example, if I post a soundcloud link, then it adds to the playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah sure it's possible it just takes a little bit of searching.  Take a look at these links:

**Soundcloud api**
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing

**Javascript inside Tumblr posts and themes**
[Javascript on Individual Tumblr Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552391/javascript-on-individual-tumblr-post)

You may need some other glue to make it work but those should get you going.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check these out and start doing it!